# Extracting RAW SQL from Rails Migration file

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails Migration, I have to extract RAW SQL from rails migration file without migrating.

This is sample conversion:

In rails migrations:

```rb
# 20230918004257_add_some_column_to_table.rb
class AddSomeColumnToTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_column :table, :column_a, :string, comment: 'column a'
    add_column :table, :column_b, :string, comment: 'column b'
    add_column :table, :column_c, :string, comment: 'column c'
  end
end
```

extracted SQL:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD `column_a` varchar(255) COMMENT 'column_a';
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD `column_b` varchar(255) COMMENT 'column_b';
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD `column_c` varchar(255) COMMENT 'column_c';
```

No matter how much I look in ActiveRecord::Migration, I don't see a method that simply extracts the sql without doing anything else. How can I just do a simple sql extraction?

Comment: Do you need to get SQL queries just for one file or for all?

Comment: And which direction?

Comment: @mechnicov for one migration file.

Comment: @max Most of the time you'll need the up direction, but of course you'll want to be able to extract the down direction as well, if possible.

Comment: What exactly do you need this for? Not that I want to question you, but your use case might help with the answer

Comment: @BenjaminScharbau sorry for not enough description about my side. My org have to communicate with DBA using SQL, but our workflow in developing rails application do not have step to extracting SQL from rails. Now, we catch SQL from log during migration on local machine. I want to automate this step for preventing human mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

1. To take all migrations queries, use whole file `db/structure.sql`

There are 2 types of [schema dumps](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you) in rails: `db/schema.rb` and `db/structure.sql`

If you need to you use raw SQL — use second one. To enable this feature add this line to `config/application.rb`

```rb
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

2. Simplest way to extract SQL queries of given migration is execution

You can look at the `git diff` of the `db/structure.sql`

Another way to run migration from console and copy output

```rb
require Rails.root.join("db/migrate/20230918004257_add_some_column_to_table.rb")

AddSomeColumnToTable.new.migrate(:up)

# or like this if needed
AddSomeColumnToTable.migrate(:down)
```

To prevent real updating of the database you can wrap this code with transaction and rollback it

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  AddSomeColumnToTable.migrate(:up)
  raise # or more elegant: raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
end
```

Also it is possible to call this methods inside [rails console sandbox](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#bin-rails-console) (all changes will rollback on exit), to enter this mode

```
rails c -s
```

Comment: It seems as if these strategies require the subject migration to be run, am I wrong? OP is asking for the SQL without running the migration.

Comment: Yep. Migrations haven't simple API like `to_sql` method

Comment: Thank you @mechnicov . But I want to just convert rails migration file to sql without migration. Like the above-mentioned `to_sql`, which is typically used to create queries.

Comment: I didn’t know sandbox mode, thanks. I will search for it.

Comment: @jeyraof I've added link to rails guides to the answer