structure.sql differs when running `rails db:schema:dump` on different machines
We are running a Ruby on Rails application with a PostgreSQL database. In the database, there is a view defined. When running rails db:migrate or rails db:schema:dump on different local development environments the created structure.sql looks slightly different.
Part of the original view definition looks like this:
WHERE name IN ('foo', 'bar')

And these are the different versions that we observe on the different developer's computers:
WHERE ((name):text = ANY (ARRAY[('foo'::character varying)::text, ('bar'::character varying)::text]))
WHERE ((name):text = ANY ((ARRAY['foo'::character varying, 'bar'::character varying])::text[]))
WHERE name::text = ANY (ARRAY['foo'::character varying::text, 'bar'::character varying::text])

As far as I understand, all those versions are technical equivalent. But it is, of course, super annoying having to deal with these structure.sql changes in Git, because that line should not change, and no change should be committed because of that slightly different dump structure.
I am looking for ideas how to debug and investigate where is difference is coming from.
What we checked so far:

We are all running the same Ruby (3.3.0), the same Ruby on Rails (7.1.3) and the same version of the pg gem (1.5.6).
We are all running the same version of PostgreSQL (15.6)
We are all setting up the database with the same script, importing the same dump and running db:migrate afterwards.


Hi @spickerman, not 100% the same thing, but we had a similar discussion not so long ago here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77848079/preventing-activerecord-migration-from-making-huge-changes-in-db-structure-sql

When you set config.active_record.schema_format = :sql Rails really just invokes the pg_dump program which does all the work. So you can pretty much eliminate Rails and everything else out of the picture completely and just try to figure out why pg_dump is giving different output. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/57cbc2e6ccd0a1095a6bbab38bcc3270555339a7/activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb#L75

The other part of the issue would be the if the statements created by the migration vary. Running a single migration to view the SQL output is doable but hacky. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77128958/extracting-raw-sql-from-rails-migration-file
